# ffmpeg afade not being applied to atrim

Tags: ffmpeg

I used ffmpeg command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -filter_complex "atrim=2:duration=6;afade=t=in:st=0:d=2" -y -vn output.mp3
```

Get error:

```
Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_afade_1
```

Why does `output.mp3` have no fade in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `;` with `,` and add [asetpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) to reset timestamp of trimmed audio:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mp3 -filter_complex "atrim=2:duration=6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,afade=t=in:st=0:d=2" -vn output.mp3
```